# Appending to list overwrites previous values

Tags: python

I am trying to make a list of dicts in order to store the values from those dicts over all the iterations I am running the sim for, but rather than actually appending them to the end of the current list Python is instead replacing all of the previously saved dicts with the current one as well as adding one more with each iteration. A simplified version of my code is as follows:

```
phist = []
for i in range(1000):
    p = Func(p,i)
    phist.append(p)
```

So when running this for the first iteration phist has one copy of p1 (dict p from the first iteration), on the second iteration phist has two copies of p2 (so phist[0] and phist[1] both give p2, and so on until I have a 1000 long list with p1000 repeated over and over again. Really seems like the append function is not at all doing what it is supposed to.

I have also tried doing this by preallocating phist=list(range(1000)) and at every iteration doing phist[i] = p, but that causes the same problem

reproducible example:

```
a = {'a': 1,
'b': 2}
def Func(a):
    a['b'] = a['b'] + a['a']
    return a

ahist = []
for i in range(10):
    a = Func(a)
    ahist.append(a)
```

Comment: It's doing _exactly_ what it's supposed to. Move `p = []` _inside_ the loop if they're supposed to be independent lists, or append a copy (with e.g. `phist.append(p[:])`), depending on what output you're actually expecting.

Comment: I need p to persist between loops because the function exists to update previous values of p over time, I can't be resetting it with every loop. Also phist.append(p[:]) doesn't work because dicts can't be sliced

Comment: What is `Func`? What is the value of `p` going in?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - we almost certainly _don't_ need 1,000 iterations but we do need to understand roughly what `Func` does and what output you're getting vs. expecting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I made a reproducible version

Comment: And what are you expecting to happen? Seems like appending a _copy_ of the dictionary would work fine, but I don't know what the expected output is. Please [edit] to give a single coherent post as if you'd provided this to start with.

Comment: `a = Func(a)` does't make a copy of the dict. `ahist` is just a list full of references to the original `dict` bound to the global `a`.

Comment: You have a global dictionary that is modified by `Func()` and each `append()` call just appends a reference to the same dictionary over and over.

Comment: The expected output is ahist=[{'a': 1, 'b':2}, {'a': 1, 'b':3} and so on]. Ok it is a bunch of references, how do I change that??

Comment: You need to make a copy of `a` before you modify it, and return that.

Comment: I recommend adding `print(a)` inside your for loop to understand what is happening.

Comment: `ahist = [{'a': 1, b: x} for x in range(10)]`.

Comment: Also read about names and values in python.

Comment: @Barmar do you mean doing c=a and then ahist.append(c) instead?

Comment: @chepner It is almost as if I made a simplified example of my actual problem, and want a solution to the actual problem, not just how to do what the simplified version does

Comment: You need to make a copy of the dict, _somewhere_. Maybe you should pass a copy to `Func`. Maybe `Func` should make a copy (it's unidiomatic for a function to mutate _and_ return its argument). Maybe you should append a copy. At least one of those needs to happen otherwise you **only have one dictionary**.

Comment: But that copy will just be the thing referenced every time it gets updated instead?

Comment: Unless I am missing something I do not understand what you all mean by copy because that does not do anything useful

Comment: @user23424688 yes. I think you believe `c = a` makes a copy. It doesn't. That merely makes *another reference* to the same object. You have to *copy the objec*. Most built-ins have a `.copy()` method you can call that will provide a shallow copy.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a debugger (e.g. https://pythontutor.com/). Also read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: you should really read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Why do you expect the output to start with `{'a': 1, 'b':2}`? That's the value of `a` before you called the function the first time, but you never save that in `ahist`.

Comment: @Barmar it was a typo, you get the idea

Comment: "So when running this for the first iteration phist has one copy of p1 (dict p from the first iteration), on the second iteration phist has two copies of p2 (so phist[0] and phist[1] both give p2, and so on until I have a 1000 long list with p1000 repeated over and over again. " IOW, that is totally incorrect. Never is a copy made, you keep re-using **the same `dict` object**. Which you mutate. Not once do you create a copy of this `dict`.  Your list ends up with multiple references to the same dict. See barmar's answer for a quick fix to demonstrate how you could make a copy.

Comment: You should clearly provide an example of input and expected output. This has more than a little whiff of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying `a` in place, and returning references to that same dictionary every time. You should make a copy of it.

```
a = {'a': 1,
     'b': 2}

def Func(d):
    new_d = d.copy()
    new_d['b'] = d['b'] + d['a']
    return new_d

ahist = []
for i in range(10):
    a = Func(a)
    ahist.append(a)
```

Comment: `Func` mutates its argument _then_ creates a copy to return?!

Comment: I fixed it. I didn't realize the caller was also reassigning the variable.

Comment: Can someone explain why this works? Like so what there is a copy of it inside the function, you are still setting it equal to the same thing outside the function

Comment: Because now it's not the same thing that you're modifying when you do `a['b'] = ...`. It's a different dictionary each time.

Comment: Each time you do `a = Func(a)` you're setting it to a different dictionary.

Comment: @user23424688 It works because `a.copy()` creates a **new dict object**. Again, this is *crucial*. Stop thinking in terms of variables, of "things inside or outside the function". Objects *don't exist inside or outside functions*. Variables *are scoped to being inside or outside a function*, and variables refer to objects. An object can be referenced from many variables (or by other objects)

Comment: @user23424688 in your code, the variable `a` that is in the global scope ('outside the function') is referring to **the same dict object**, because the same dict object is returned by the function call `Func(a)`. In the code in this answer, the dict returned by `Func` is a *copy* (which is made on the line `a = a.copy()`). The name of the variable is irrelevant, btw, it could be `banana`, in both cases, they would simply be local variables ('inside the function')